# Lose of DOC file format when loading into rich text box

Tags: c#, windows

I am loosing format of doc file when i load into rich text box. what shoud i do?

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        RichTextBox rt = new RichTextBox();
        rt.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\rich.doc");

        rt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(rt);            
 }
```

Comment: A `.doc` file!? They haven't been mainstream for more than a decade. Most doc files around now are either in archival storage or are infection vectors. I think if you want to load a formatted file, it has to be an RTF file (another ancient Word format, but safer). That's what the docs say: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.loadfile?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_RichTextBox_LoadFile_System_String_ RTF is the native text representation in a rich text box (I think)

Comment: Here i want doc file opened in richtextbox without loosing format(bgcolors,images,etc) of it.

Comment: Yup, and I'd like to see the end of the pandemic. But, the only file format containing formatted text that a RichTextBox can load properly is RTF (RTF, by the way, stands for _Rich Text Format_). Read the docs

Answer (score 0):

A DOC file is not rich text formatted, but instead uses its own format, which is now also very old (replaced by DOCX).

Word can save to RTF format, but you need to do this explicitly when saving in Word, which means losing a lot of the DOC formatting details.

Read also this:

http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-rtf-and-doc/

Comment: thanks for the information as i am bignner in this field.